# Installing beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm new with latex and especially with beamer, I'm trying to use the automatic wizard that is supposed to create an automatic code for my presentation. My code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{MyName}
\title{Try}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
%\logo{} 
%\institute{} 
%\date{} 
%\subject{} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

%\begin{frame}
%\tableofcontents
%\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{•}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But I get the error: `undefined control sequence`. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Please copy and paste the actual error message.  But I'd be very surprised if this and samcarter's answer are giving the same error message.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems:

- you need `beamer` as documentclass and not article (in theory you could load the `beamerarticle` package to make this compilable, but you wouldn't get a presentation...)
- you can't use special characters like `•` if you explicitly switch off the default utf8 input by loading `\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}`. You should really, really, really double check if your file is really not utf8, which would be highly unusual this millennium. Don't use this encoding unless you really need to.
- you should not use the syntax `\begin{frame}{...}` -- that's at best around for legacy reasons. Use the proper `\begin{frame}\frametitle{...}` syntax instead. This is much more robust and flexible
- you don't need to load all these `ams` packages, beamer loads them by default
- you don't need to load `grpahicx`, beamer loads this for you

---

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer} 

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usepackage[ascii]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{MyName}
\title{Try}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent} 
%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
%\logo{} 
%\institute{} 
%\date{} 
%\subject{} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

%\begin{frame}
%\tableofcontents
%\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I still get the same error :(

Comment: @PhysicsStudent Then please add your complete .log file